# show/hide transition not triggering properly because of ng-animate

Tags: angularjs, css-transitions, ng-class, angularjs-animation

Angularjs 1.2.6 scenario: 2 inputs, 1 textbox (sounds kinda dirty). The inputs both trigger a show / hide transition on blur / focus events and focus always comes after blur if click from one input to another. Even the text binding shows the proper current state (show = `true` or `false`).

```html
<div class="hint fade" ng-class="{in: info.show}">info.text<div>
```

The style classes <kbd>.fade</kbd> and <kbd>.in</kbd> come from bootstrap. They have a CSS3 transition but in the fiddle I kept it simple (not including bootstrap.css).

`info.show` is switched on focus / blur events.

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7vk7p/2/)**

**Without ngAnimate it works perfect**. When ngAnimate is added as dependency, transitions stop working properly. In the jsfiddle, simply remove ngAnimate (leaving an empty array) and it works just fine.

Just click on one input: textbox fades in. Now directly click the other input: text updates properly, but box still fades out.

Filed a [bug-report](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5588), but in the meantime I'm looking for a work-around. Got suggestions?

Comment: A [fix](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5588) has already been merged into the Angular code.

Comment: I hit the same issue today.